# How to programmatically post a link to Microsoft channel message?

Tags: microsoft-teams

when you post a link in a message in a Microsoft team channel (from the graphical interface), it adds a preview to the message (image + description).
How can we achieve the same programmatically?

I tried to create a message that contained an  link but the magic didn't occur.

If I then post the same link through the graphical interface and then programmatically dump the 2 messages, they are identical!
However the message created programmatically doesn't show the preview.

Added screenshot:
In Microsoft teams, if I post a message with a link ( here it is www.microsoft.com), it automatically adds the picture and description.
I want achieve the same programmatically.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to [composeExtensions messageHandlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/messaging-extensions/search-extensions#receive-requests-from-links-inserted-into-the-compose-message-box) experience?

Comment: not sure to understand your question. I added a picture in the question.

Comment: In UI, user gets to decide whether to send preview or not (Close button right to preview). Currently, It is not supported when you are sending message programmatically.